# Breakpoint occasionally not hit on IIS 7.5 in integrated mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, iis

I have a Web API application created on Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Then I have this code:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
 {
     // POST api/product
     public void Post([FromBody]string value, HttpRequestMessage request)
     {
         int i = 5;
     }
 ...
```

I use "Use Local IIS Web Server" to debug the application on IIS 7.5/Windows 7. The application runs in a pool with `Maximum Worker Processes = 1`, in integrated mode.

I have a breakpoint in `int i = 5;`

I press F5 on visual web developer, then I point my browser to `http://localhost/`. The home page contains a simple form which I use to post to the webservice. The post URL is /mcp.test/api/product . Most of the times the breakpoint is hit as expected. Occasionaly, specially after I leave the application paused in the breakpoint for a long time, and then continue (F5), the break point is not hit when I post the form. I still get the same response (status code 204) as when the breakpoint is hit, but without a hit.

IIS log:

> 2015-02-03 22:12:01 ::1 POST /mcp.test/api/product - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/40.0.2214.93+Safari/537.36 204 0 0 999
>
> 2015-02-03 22:12:03 ::1 POST /mcp.test/api/product - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/40.0.2214.93+Safari/537.36 204 0 0 3

The first line is a breakpoint hit (999 is the time it took), the second line is a breakpoint miss (it takes only 3 in time).

The task manager shows only one w3wp.exe worker process running.

How can I hit the breakpoint 100% of times?

Comment: did you check the process id ? may be the initial process was recycled.

Comment: The process id did not change. A recycled process would have a diferente id always?